# Removing front element in LinkedList gives garbage

Tags: c++, linked-list

this is the code :

```
void deleteNodebyValue(struct Node *head, int data){
    Node *cur = head;
    Node *prevNode = head;
    while(cur){

        if(cur->data == data){
            //cout << "if(cur->data == data)" << endl;
            if(cur == head){
                cout <<"if(cur == head)" << endl;
                //head = cur->next;
                return;

            } else{
                prevNode->next = cur->next;

            }

            delete cur;
            return;

        }

        prevNode = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

It works for any node but front(first/head) node.
If I try to delete the first node it gives garbage :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to modify where `head` points in the function, the problem is that you pass `head` *by value* which means that the pointer is copied and in the function you only modify the copy locally. You need to pass the `head` pointer by reference:

```
void deleteNodebyValue(struct Node *&head, int data){...}
```

Then of course you can't return directly in that case, you still need to actually delete the node.